# all latitude longitude nearby a specifiic point( latitude longitude)

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

i'm having millions of latitude and longitude which i want to store on firebase,

after storing i want to retrieve all the nearby latitude and longitude(from my stored latitude longitude on firebase) from a specific point(latitude and longitude)

my problem is how should i store all my millions of latitude longitude so that i can fetch all the nearby lat long from a specific point(lat long)

i was thinking to store all the lat long in Firebase Cloud Firestore but after storing how i will be fetching all the nearby lat longs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have native support for geoqueries, but there's a good documentation page on how you can build that yourself [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

I also recommend checking out some of the previous questions on this topic [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+google-cloud-firestore+nearby).